# Find Text in HTML with Regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some text

```
Trotz­dem gibt es Unter­su­chun­gen, die nahe­le­gen, dass bis zu 20% der Stu­die­ren­den in Deutsch­land wäh­rend der Prü­fungs­vor­be­rei­tung Rita­lin ein­schmeis­sen [2], Repor­ta­gen, dass bri­ti­sche Stu­die­rende Moda­fi­nil bes­tens ken­nen[3] und Stu­die­rende welt­weit auch nach der Silk Road — einem mitt­ler­weile ein­ge­stell­ten Schwarz­markt im Deep Web – mit ille­ga­len „Nootro­pics“ experimentieren.
```

and I have some HTML

```
<p>Die <span class="caps">GDS</span> zeich­net also das Bild einer Gesell­schaft, in der Dro­gen pri­mär Rausch, Genuss und Spass sind. Tabak ist zwar das bekann­teste – und unge­sün­deste – Mit­tel gegen Stress, aber sonst sind die Leis­tungs­stei­ge­rer in der Liste weit abge­schla­gen. Trotz­dem gibt es Unter­su­chun­gen, die nahe­le­gen, dass bis zu 20% der Stu­die­ren­den in Deutsch­land wäh­rend der Prü­fungs­vor­be­rei­tung Rita­lin ein­schmeis­sen <a href="#_ftn2" name="_ftnref2">[2]</a>, Repor­ta­gen, dass bri­ti­sche Stu­die­rende Moda­fi­nil bes­tens ken­nen<a href="#_ftn3" name="_ftnref3">[3]</a> und Stu­die­rende welt­weit auch nach der <a href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk_Road" target="_blank">Silk Road</a> — einem mitt­ler­weile ein­ge­stell­ten Schwarz­markt im Deep Web – mit ille­ga­len „Nootro­pics“ experimentieren.</p>
```

To find the text in the HTML I produce some crazy ass regex, where I split by the spaces and join again with

```
\s*?(?:<\/?[^>]*?>)?\s*?
```

That works most of the time as seen here: https://regex101.com/r/hG9lT9/1

In the case stated on top it doesn't work because there is a comma after a html tag and there are also different dashes. So I'm searching to create a more general regex expression to fit the cause.

Here is the example that doesn't work: https://regex101.com/r/hG9lT9/2

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1

Comment: @freefaller Ultimate comment..

Comment: You can get the text from a given HTML string with JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: Thanks freefaller. I will abandon my futile endeavour. :)

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3478852)

Comment: I don't actually need to parse html. I need to parse text with unknown characters in between words.

Answer (score -4):

Split by : `<[^>]*>`? (regex for the html tags)

Comment: See the comments above, and specifically @tasos-k's comment for how to do it legitimately.